# Error encountered while building trpl-ebook: patterns aren't allowed in methods without bodies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to generate the epub ebook of [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition) for my Kindle.

I downloaded [this Github project](https://github.com/killercup/trpl-ebook) to rebuild the book the second edition draft. When I do `cargo run --release`, I encounter the following error:

```
nabarun@pal:~/codesl/trpl-ebook (git:master) $ cargo run --release
   Compiling rustc-serialize v0.3.19
   Compiling memchr v0.1.11
   Compiling kernel32-sys v0.2.2
error[E0642]: patterns aren't allowed in methods without bodies
   --> /home/nabarun/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustc-serialize-0.3.19/src/serialize.rs:147:45
    |
147 |                                             &f_name: &str,
    |                                             ^^^^^^^

   Compiling aho-corasick v0.5.3
   Compiling thread-id v2.0.0
   Compiling thread_local v0.2.7
   Compiling regex v0.1.77
error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `rustc-serialize`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

I tried to search and debug the error but couldn't do so owing to my lack of knowledge of Rust at the moment. Did anyone else encounter this error?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Rust 1.25.0-nightly (b5392f545 2018-01-08), xargo 0.3.10, cargo 0.25.0-nightly (a88fbace4 2017-12-29)

I have also [filed an issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/killercup/trpl-ebook/issues/49).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[rustc-serialize 0.3.19](https://crates.io/crates/rustc-serialize/0.3.19) was released on April 4, 2016. It includes the syntax:

```
fn read_enum_struct_variant_field<T, F>(
    &mut self,
    &f_name: &str, // This is no longer allowed
    f_idx: usize,
    f: F,
) -> Result<T, Self::Error>;
```

This syntax was erroneously allowed until [Oct 21, 2016 (Rust 1.14.0)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/811a2b91de8fe0c6bbd8d49186d0d5be192f644e) when it was turned into a warning. On [Nov 4, 2017 (Rust 1.23.0)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/f7b4b88840d872909a67e5f9623281e3e2165fba), this became an error.

The solution is to update the version of rustc-serialize:

```
cargo update -p rustc-serialize
```